# Creating an excel file or CSV from Workbench with a query

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, amazon-redshift

I appreciate your help here as this is my first time using SQL Workbench.

I am connected to my database. I have a table called "apartments" with a column named "apt_name". For every row that contains abc, I want the value in column "zip" and I need that data exported.

So far I can't even get this to work by entering it into the Statement 1 tab and hitting the execute button. "Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "CONTAINS".

SELECT * FROM apartments WHERE apt_name CONTAINS 'abc'

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

SELECT * FROM apartments WHERE 0<>CHARINDEX('abc',apt_name)

Comment: what about the value in column "zip"?